# mysql dbi connection: works in irb, not in script?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am trying to use the rubygem DBI to connect to MYSQL on Windows 7; I can connect using irb but not from within a ruby script, which has stumped me for a few days now...

Here is my gem env output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.28
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 545) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby193/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/rick/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Here is my irb connection:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'dbi'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> dbh=DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306", "rick",>
=> #<DBI::DatabaseHandle:0x2c30bb0 @handle=#<DBI::DBD::Mysql::Database:0x2c30dd8
 @handle=#<Mysql:0x2c30f28>, @attr={"AutoCommit"=>true}, @have_transactions=true
, @mutex=#<Mutex:0x2c30bf8>>, @trace_output=nil, @trace_mode=nil, @convert_types
=true, @driver_name="Mysql">
irb(main):005:0> row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
=> ["5.5.25a"]
irb(main):006:0> puts row
5.5.25a
=> nil
irb(main):007:0>
```

And here is my script:

```
require 'DBI'
require 'mysql'

# connect to the MySQL server
begin
     dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:wikifracdb:127.0.0.1;port=3306", "rick", "rick")
     # get server version string and display it
     row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
     puts "Server version: " + row[0]
   rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
     puts "An error occurred"
     puts "Error code: #{e.err}"
     puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
   ensure
     # disconnect from server
     dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

But when I run my script, I get:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:93: warning: already in
itialized constant VERSION
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:96: warning: already in
itialized constant API_VERSION
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:100: warning: already i
nitialized constant DEFAULT_TRACE_MODE
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/dbi-0.4.5/lib/dbi.rb:101: warning: already i
nitialized constant DEFAULT_TRACE_OUTPUT
An error occurred
Error code: 2003
Error message: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

I have Windows Firewall turned off.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated...this has been driving me crazy!

Comment: I tried connecting without installing dbb-mysql and got an error. Do you have dbd-mysql installed in your system? After installing dbd-mysql Im able to connect to db without issues.

Comment: @user944938: I installed dbd-mysql, and required it, but no joy...but your evidence will help me trouble-shoot another attempt...thanks.

Comment: I don't think the dbd-mysql gem is involved; I should be able to connect with the DBI gem. I know mysql is working, because I can connect to this same database in a mysql terminal window...so why Ruby cannot connect to the same database, with the same user/password, is still a mystery...